# Getting top 5 values from a file in python?

Tags: python

So i have a list that has stores two variables, the score, and the username of each player, if I want to pick the top 5 scores out of the file and print it, how would i go about it?

I cant think of a solution to do this as of right now.

Edit:
Currently this is what i have to write to the file that stores the scores

```
def QuizEnd():
global points
points = str(points)
print('Thank you for playing,', login.username.title() + ', your score was:', points)
with open('scorefile.txt', 'r+') as scfile:
    scfile.write(login.username.title())
    scfile.write('-')
    scfile.write(points)
    scfile.write('\n')
    scfile.close
```

Comment: We need more information to help you. It would be a good start to show an excerpt of your file.

Comment: Please consult the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to understand why your question is attracting downvotes.

Comment: You need to show the format of your file, is it in a list, or how? And you are using global points, that is not recommended.

Comment: How about reading the file into an array, then sorting the array and picking the top 5? That's three different things though, so I suggest you ask another question if you have a problem with any of them. At the moment this isn't a single question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. This will read your text file to df:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('scoreline.txt', sep=" ", header=None) #sep depends on your file, it can be space, semicolon or anything.
data.columns = ["Score", "Username",] # Put names of your column
```

Step 2: Find top 5 rows of data df:

```
data.nlargest(5, columns=['Score'])
```

Comment: there seems to be an error with 'pd' it says that it is not defined. Is there a library i need to import?

Comment: Python cannot find the module 'pandas'

Comment: then do `pip install pandas` in your anaconda prompt or cmd or just read how to install pandas package in python